# Rotation easing algorithm not working in XNA

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript-3, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

I am trying to ease (gradually move) the rotation of an object to an arbitrary position.  The angle of rotation is determined by a Virtual Thumbstick class which returns X/Y coordinates between -1 and 1.  If there is no movement on the thumbstick, I am rotating back to point to 0, except I am compensating for the angle of the sprite's image.

The problem I am having is that this code will only allow approximately 1.5 rotations (anywhere between -3*PI and 3*PI) instead of continuous rotation.  Using Math.Atan2 with the X/Y coords of the thumbsticks, the returned angle is constrained between -PI and PI but allows continuous rotation.  Also, if I rotate the object in one direction and release the thumbstick, it will rotate back to top from the direction it came.  I want it to rotate back to the top on the shortest route.

```
if (VirtualThumbsticks.LeftThumbstick.Length() > .2f)
{
    double rotateTo = Math.Atan2(VirtualThumbsticks.LeftThumbstick.Y, VirtualThumbsticks.LeftThumbstick.X);

    if (rotateTo > Rotation + Math.PI) rotateTo -= (Math.PI * 2);
    if (rotateTo < Rotation - Math.PI) rotateTo += (Math.PI * 2);

    Rotation += (rotateTo - Rotation) * 0.2;
}
else
{
    Rotation += (-1.57079 - Rotation) *0.2;
}
```

If there are any Flash/ActionScript game developers that know what I'm talking about, please chime in as I can apply that to C#.

Thanks in advance, everyone!

EDIT:

This chunk of code works flawlessly in AS3:

```
function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void
{
    var curMouseX = Math.round(-(arrow.x - stage.mouseX));//(stage.stageWidth/2)-(stage.mouseX/2);
    var curMouseY = Math.round(-(arrow.y - stage.mouseY));//(stage.stageHeight/2)-(stage.mouseY/2);
    var angleTo:Number = Math.atan2(curMouseX, -curMouseY) * TO_DEGREES;
    if (angleTo > arrow.rotation+180) angleTo -= 360;
    if (angleTo < arrow.rotation-180) angleTo += 360;

    tf_angle.text = angleTo.toString();
    tf_mouseX.text = curMouseX.toString();
    tf_mouseY.text = curMouseY.toString();

    arrow.rotation += (angleTo - arrow.rotation) * 0.2;
}
```

I'm beginning to wonder if there is an issue with my types or typecasting that is causing the problem.  If anyone has any ideas, your input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Tigran - The rotation is not continuous.  It hits a wall after rotating 1.5 times in either direction and snaps back.  Also, when letting go of the thumbstick, it snaps back to 0 (or -1.57097 in this case) from the direction it came.  Please re-read the question for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved.  The problem was lying in the rotation value not being "normalized".  Basically, if the rotation value exceeds Math.PI*2, it must return to 0... and if the rotation value falls below 0, it must return to Math.PI*2.

The last comment on this page has solved my problem and the rotation is normalized now.

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/27527.aspx

My resulting code:

```
if (VirtualThumbsticks.LeftThumbstick.Length() > .2f)
{
    float angleTo = (float)Math.Atan2(VirtualThumbsticks.LeftThumbstick.Y, VirtualThumbsticks.LeftThumbstick.X);

    if (angleTo > Rotation + Math.PI) angleTo -= (float)(Math.PI * 2);
    if (angleTo < Rotation - Math.PI) angleTo += (float)(Math.PI * 2);

    accelerationRotation += (angleTo - Rotation) * (float)0.25;

}
else
{
    accelerationRotation += ((float)(Math.PI / 2) - Rotation) * (float)0.2;
}

Rotation = Wrap(accelerationRotation, 0, (float)Math.PI * 2);
```

The Wrap function is as follows:

```
public static float Wrap(float value, float lower, float upper)
{
    unchecked
    {
        if (lower >= upper)
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("rotary bounds out of negative or zero size");
        }

        float distance = upper - lower;

        float times = (float)Math.Floor((value - lower) / distance);

        return value - (times * distance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is written in C# using XML, so the actionscript parallel may not apply, but i bet that it does. In Flash, rotations are adjusted at the end of every frame, because there is little benefit in storing a rotation transform of 123456789 degrees. so the transform resets to the modulo value of the rotation.

However, in calculating shortest rotation, you can run into problems if you are expecting *some large number* and comparing it to some other number instead of calculating their relative positions using their modulo values.

Maybe this is the source of the problem. its just a guess.

On the odd chance you are not familiar with it, the modulo operator - aka percent sign - "%" will give you the remainder of division. this is helpful for numbers that loop, like grid alignments, and rotations.

Example:

```
21 % 5 = 1;
 720 % 360 = 0;
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but I don't understand how to apply that logic to my problem.  That's more telling me that I can run into problems while calculating shortest rotation.  Also, not quite sure what you mean by "written in C# using XML".